# Qemu versatilepb booting u-boot from flash

Tags: qemu, u-boot

I am new in qemu an I want to learn something about it.
I am running an u-boot in qemu using kernel parameter like this way:

buldung uboot:

```
make versatileqemu_config
```

running qemu:

```
qemu-system-arm -M versatilepb -m 128M -serial stdio -kernel u-boot.bin -display none
```

An all is working fine, but now I want to run uboot from flash.
Creating flash image in this way:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=flash.bin bs=256k count=256
dd if=u-boot.bin of=flash.bin bs=256k conv=notrunc
```

An try to run it:

```
qemu-system-arm -M versatilepb -m 128M -serial stdio -pflash flash.bin -display none
```

Efect is that there is crash, it seems that u-boot is not loaded:

```
qemu: fatal: Trying to execute code outside RAM or ROM at 0x08000000

R00=00000000 R01=00000000 R02=00000000 R03=00000000
R04=00000000 R05=00000000 R06=00000000 R07=00000000
R08=00000000 R09=00000000 R10=00000000 R11=00000000
R12=00000000 R13=00000000 R14=00000000 R15=08000000
PSR=400001d3 -Z-- A svc32
s00=00000000 s01=00000000 d00=0000000000000000
s02=00000000 s03=00000000 d01=0000000000000000
s04=00000000 s05=00000000 d02=0000000000000000
s06=00000000 s07=00000000 d03=0000000000000000
s08=00000000 s09=00000000 d04=0000000000000000
s10=00000000 s11=00000000 d05=0000000000000000
s12=00000000 s13=00000000 d06=0000000000000000
s14=00000000 s15=00000000 d07=0000000000000000
s16=00000000 s17=00000000 d08=0000000000000000
s18=00000000 s19=00000000 d09=0000000000000000
s20=00000000 s21=00000000 d10=0000000000000000
s22=00000000 s23=00000000 d11=0000000000000000
s24=00000000 s25=00000000 d12=0000000000000000
s26=00000000 s27=00000000 d13=0000000000000000
s28=00000000 s29=00000000 d14=0000000000000000
s30=00000000 s31=00000000 d15=0000000000000000
FPSCR: 00000000
Aborted (core dumped)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In executing uboot, it will try to load the kernel for run, but in flash.bin you created , there is nothing can be run as a kernel, so a crash is unavoidable.